EKS and ECR VPC Endpoints
I'm trying to configure VPC endpoints for ECR from EKS. The EKS cluster has two public subnets. I'm using Terraform to provision everything.
# VPC for EKS Cluster
resource "aws_vpc" "primary" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"

  enable_dns_support   = true
  enable_dns_hostnames = true

  tags = {
    environment = var.environment
    Name        = "${var.environment}-eks-vpc"
  }

}


# Primary Subnet for EKS
resource "aws_subnet" "eks_primary" {
  vpc_id                  = var.eks_vpc_id
  cidr_block              = "10.0.1.0/24"
  availability_zone       = "eu-central-1a"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.environment}-eks-primary-subnet"
  }
}

# Secondary Subnet for EKS
resource "aws_subnet" "eks_secondary" {
  vpc_id                  = var.eks_vpc_id
  cidr_block              = "10.0.2.0/24"
  availability_zone       = "eu-central-1b"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.environment}-eks-secondary-subnet"
  }
}

map_public_ip_on_launch = true is set so it assigns public IP as expected. And below is my EKS TF config.
resource "aws_eks_cluster" "main" {
  name     = "hehe-${var.environment}"
  role_arn = var.role_arn_primary

  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids = [var.eks_subnet_id_primary, var.eks_subnet_id_secondary]
  }

  tags = {
    environment = var.environment
  }

}

resource "aws_eks_node_group" "main" {
  cluster_name    = aws_eks_cluster.main.name
  node_group_name = "system"
  node_role_arn   = var.role_arn_secondary
  subnet_ids      = [var.eks_subnet_id_primary, var.eks_subnet_id_secondary]

  tags = {
    environment = var.environment
  }

  scaling_config {
    desired_size = 1
    max_size     = 2
    min_size     = 1
  }

  update_config {
    max_unavailable = 1
  }

}

Below are the VPC endpoints for ECR in the public subnet.
# VPC Endpoint for ECR API in the EKS VPC
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "ecr_api" {
  vpc_id             = var.eks_vpc_id
  service_name       = "com.amazonaws.eu-central-1.ecr.api"
  subnet_ids         = [var.eks_primary_subnet_id, var.eks_secondary_subnet_id]
  security_group_ids = [var.eks_security_group_id]
  vpc_endpoint_type  = "Interface"

  private_dns_enabled = true


  tags = {
    environment = var.environment
    Name        = "${var.environment}-vpc-endpoint-api"
  }

}

# VPC Endpoint for ECR DKR API in the EKS VPC
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "ecr_dkr" {
  vpc_id             = var.eks_vpc_id
  service_name       = "com.amazonaws.eu-central-1.ecr.dkr"
  subnet_ids         = [var.eks_primary_subnet_id, var.eks_secondary_subnet_id]
  security_group_ids = [var.eks_security_group_id]
  vpc_endpoint_type  = "Interface"

  private_dns_enabled = true

  tags = {
    environment = var.environment
    Name        = "${var.environment}-vpc-endpoint-dkr"
  }

}

# VPC Endpoint for ECR S3 API in the EKS VPC
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "s3" {
  vpc_id             = var.eks_vpc_id
  service_name       = "com.amazonaws.eu-central-1.s3"
  security_group_ids = [var.eks_security_group_id]
  vpc_endpoint_type = "Gateway"

  route_table_ids = [var.route_table_id]

  tags = {
    environment = var.environment
    Name        = "${var.environment}-vpc-endpoint-s3"
  }

}

And I get below error:

create: unexpected state 'CREATE_FAILED', wanted target 'ACTIVE'. last
error: NodeCreationFailure: Instances failed to join the kubernetes
cluster

EKS NodeGroup cannot join the EKS cluster.
But if I remove enable_dns_support = true and enable_dns_hostnames = true from VPC, the NodeGroup can join the EKS cluster but then nslookup for ECR endpoint doesn't resolve to private IP. Any idea what's wrong?

Ensure that your DHCP options of your vpc have [AmazonProvidedDNS][1] as value in the list of DNS in terraform aws_vpc_dhcp_options.
Another point I think you need to define also an endpoint for EC2 com.amazonaws.region-code.ec2 as it's required for private EKS configuration. but it's not clear in your post if you try to configure EKS in private mode or public mode.

I can see AmazonProvidedDNS already configured in VPC

But still NodeGroup fails to connect to Kubernetes cluster

What about ec2 endpoint ?

My EKS cluster's API is Public though. So do I need to create an EC2 endpoint?

VPC Endpoint are mainly used to communicate in private, if your control plane have a public endpoint and worker nodes can communicate with other AWS services publicly you do not need it. and that's what you encounter when your nodes join the cluster but you can't resolve ECR endpoint publicly as they are private
